# Webview causes crash of WinRT App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am having a webivew in my app. In some cases app crashes and not even caught in App_UnhandledException. I tried unchecking in visual studio Debug->Option and settings-> Just in Time-> Uncheck script but still its causing the issue when user clicks on few links.

**I noticed the error is coming only in case of https url.**

I am having the same error like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7c6d3e34-1a07-4aed-acad-ee6aac3c82cd/webview-crash-accidentally)

Comment: Did you try to run in release mode  ?

Comment: yes I tried it with release mode or even creating a package and then running it but with no luck.